# From which table I will get subcategory name?

Tags: magento-1.7, category

Can anyone tell me the table from where I will get subcategory name. I want to fire query using table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento use **Eav structure** for ***Category, product, customer data management.***

**name** field  is a `varchar` type attribute.

As per as, magento *Eav attribute structure* that **name** field values are save at `catalog_category_entity_varchar` table.

Answer (score 1):

Magento category is an EAV entity. So you cannot retrieve the information you wanted from a single table.

Explaining EAV concept is out of scope with regards to this question. However you can use **[Wiki document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model)** for a good start. So in short, An EAV entity is stored using multiple tables and to retrieve a "valid data" you need to join multiple tables.

Answer (score 0):

Since magento database uses EAV ( Entity, Attribute, Value ) structure to manage everything including sub-categories that you are looking for. The list of Categories & Subcategories can be found on `catalog_category_entity_varchar` table.

> Note : Simple sql query is not a best magento way of obtaining category
>   and subcategories.

For geting categories name you can also use catalog/category collection.

```
//Load catalog category model collection
<?php $categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection();?>

<?php foreach ($categories as $category): ?>
<?php echo '<pre>';?>
<?php print_r ($category->getData('name')); ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

The above code will print all categories name.

For detail refer this blog : http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-get-list-of-all-categories/

Thanks :)